# Why are standalone objects and static archives not treated the same way when generating a shared library?

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have been reading with a lot of interest this article:
https://anadoxin.org/blog/control-over-symbol-exports-in-gcc.html/

It has a specific section entitled 'Static library used by a shared library problems' which caught my attention.
I've been experimenting a little bit beyond what the article describes, and there is something that I don't quite understand.

Using code snippets from the article, say I first create a trivial static library:

```
g++ util.cpp -o util.o -c -fPIC
ar r libutil.a util.o
```

Then I independently create a standalone object:

```
g++ code.cpp -o code.o -c -fPIC
```

At last, I create a shared library from the combination of both:

```
g++ code.o libutil.a -shared -o libcode.so
```

Now, as described in the article, if I look at the export table of the shared library, everything is as I expect:

```
$ nm -CD libcode.so | grep " T "
000000000000124c T _fini
0000000000001000 T _init
0000000000001167 T entry_point()
00000000000011d1 T util_function()
0000000000001145 T function1()
```

What I do not understand though, is that if I exclude `code.o` from the shared library and only build it from the static archive:

```
g++ libutil.a -shared -o libcode.so
```

then in this case the export table of the shared library is totally empty:

```
$ nm -CD libcode.so | grep " T "
00000000000010f8 T _fini
0000000000001000 T _init
```

I figured out that in order to get the expected behaviour, I need to build the shared library as follows:

```
g++ -Wl,--whole-archive libutil.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -shared -o libcode.so
```

In this case, symbols from the archive are exported as expected:

```
$ nm -CD libcode.so | grep " T "
00000000000011a0 T _fini
0000000000001000 T _init
0000000000001125 T util_function()
```

The way I look at it, static archives are simply a collection of standalone objects. However, when creating the shared library, it seems that static archives and standalone objects are treated slightly differently. Why is it necessary to use `-Wl,--whole-archive` when the shared library is created from static archives without any standalone objects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it necessary to use -Wl,--whole-archive when the shared library is created from static archives without any standalone objects ?

Because that's [how archive libraries](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) are designed to work -- their *whole purpose* it to provide *needed* objects, while leaving unneeded objects out of the link.

Comment: I like the succinct but crystal-clear answer ;-).
There still seems to be a contradiction somewhere though. If I do `g++ libutil.a -shared -o libcode.so`, all objects in the archive are unneeded, so the shared object does not contain anything. That makes sense and follows the principle you mentioned.
But if I do `g++ code.o libutil.a -shared -o libcode.so`, some objects in the archive are now needed. They should be left out of the link, yet the opposite happens by default (`util_function` is exported). Why is it ? Maybe I'm confusing different concepts....

Comment: @DaveC Why should `util_function` be left out of the link? Is the object file which defines `util_function` not needed by anything in `code.o`? In any case, it's better to ask a _detailed_ question about it, preferably with MCVE.

Comment: I just managed to confuse myself very badly...  If some objects in the archive are needed., they are included in the link and that makes perfect sense. The slightly unrelated question is whether or not these needed objects are exported by the shared library, which is what the articles talks about and what `-fvisibility=hidden` controls.

Comment: For correctness, I should have said 'whether or not symbols defined in these needed objects are exported by the shared library' but it's too late to edit now...

Comment: @DaveC By default, _everything_ is exported. But `__attribute__((visibility...))` and `-fvisibility=...` can change the exported set of symbols, and so can a linker script.